# CSS3 Moon Eclipse shape

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes, pseudo-class

How can I make the following shape in CSS3, without using pseudo-classes like ":before"?

[image: Eclipse shape]

I did it very easy with :before, but the thing is that I don't want to have a solid element on the gray area (see JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/2/)

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div:before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 110%;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: -5%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: [This website](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) might help you. There is not an example for your shape though.

Comment: This may also help: [Flexible Google-style loader with CSS](http://lea.verou.me/2013/11/flexible-google-style-loader-with-css/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use border width:

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-width: 0;
    border-left:solid 10px red;
}
```

Scientifically inaccurate example: http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/4/

Keep in mind that the outer shape is *not* a perfect circle, because the border is added to the width. You can compensate by reducing the width, or by using [`Box-sizing: Border-box`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

Comment: n1, throw in a `transform: scaleX(0.8)` and you're there

Comment: Thank you, your solution is relevant. However, I want the shape to be exactly the same as in the picture. I tried something else, but still, it's not what I need: http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/5/

Answer (score 2):

To get the effect of a small circle eclipsed by a larger circle, you can add a shadow to a transparent element:

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    box-shadow: -23px 0 0px -15px #ff8;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/6/

Comment: Examples with with multiple shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/7 , http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/8 . This is pretty fun.

Comment: Another option is having the shadow `inset`: http://jsfiddle.net/aUdLr/9/ . I'm pretty sure you can get what you need by playing with the numbers a little.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest CSS3 solution that comes to my mind:

```
div:before {
    font: 80px serif;
    color: red;
    content: "(";
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cLtwA/)

(Now seriously- if you want a good amount of control over the shape, I suggest to use SVG.)